# Git error when pulling/cloning: repository corrupted? How to fix?

Tags: git

I have a problem with my git repository:

```
git pull origin master
error: unable to find fd0b73869242ccaeb279c9e48641b24af5d5e586
fatal: oops (fd0b73869242ccaeb279c9e48641b24af5d5e586)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Notice that the repository is between my laptop and my desktop computer, so I have sources in another directory and is not a problem to "delete and recreate" my git repository.

My last problem with git was a naming issue like XCombobox renamed to XComboBox, this created a lot of problems for my repository. After fixing it, I never pulled to the laptop for long time.

Now I'm trying to pull on the laptop and I'm having this issue.
Are there any possibility to fix the repository? How to eventually reset it by using all data on my desktop repository?

Thanks for any suggestion

**Edit 1:**

If I try to clone the repository I get `fatal: unable to read tree [...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by myself looking through the web to fix the remote repository:
http://rewoo.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/recover-a-corrupt-git-bare-repository/

This fixed my problem, I run only the `git fsck --full` and the `git gc --prune=today`

Now cloning and pulling works again.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, with a somewhat simar setup (sharing a central bare repo over a windows network amongst several computers).

For some reason, on one of the computers that had cloned the central repo nothing was working all of a sudden. Pulling and fetching resulted in the error you described.
The strange thing was that on another computer on the network, cloning the central repo worked fine.
So the problem was only occurring on a specific computer used by one specific developer on the network.

It turned out to be corrupted Windows sharing permissions. What fixed it was removing the affected user's access permissions for the central repo folder, applying the change, and then re-adding in the permissions back.

Comment: Really weird behavior O.o

Comment: Yes, really weird!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something isn't looking in the correct location. You can check out the .git/config file and make sure that your path names are correct. You should just be able to modify this file and then try another pull.

Comment: Should I check them on the "remote" repository or on the laptop one? Notice: if I try to clone the repository I get **fatal: Unable to read tree [...]**

Comment: Make sure that the "remote" repo on your laptop is pointed to the correct location on your desktop. http://geekanddad.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/git-between-two-local-machines-setup-self-reminder/ This post may help you set up the paths

Comment: The repository is correctly set, I used it 'till now when this issue showed up.